# Faulty fonts on Lazarus

Tags: fonts, fedora, lazarus

I've recently installed FPC 2.2.2 and Lazarus 0.9.6 on my Acer Aspire One, so I can cross-compile some apps and to my dismay, the fonts for the menus all are little squares.

Has anyone had a similar problem with Lazarus on a Fedora Core instalation that could give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=5803.0) might help even though its for Fedora Core 8 rather than 10. I've stuck with Linpus and had to do the same for Lazarus to get the fonts displaying ok.

Answer (score 1):

Recompiled with "make LCL_PLATFORM=gtk2"  The default is (still) GTK1, which looks shitty nowadays. (it never was a beauty, but somehow distro's don't maintain it as well anymore, because in recent distros it even looks worse?)

Comment: Thanks Marco. I'll try that. But will have to download sources since I used the *.rpms