# Linux linker flag -lXi not finding lib when compiling Lazarus code

Tags: linux, linker, lazarus, freepascal, fpc

After I solved my [first problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673086/faulty-fonts-on-lazarus) I got into another one.
Looks like I'm missing some kind of library, making the linker complain that the -lXi is not working.

I've included most of the Xorg devel packages, what more do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking to "-lXi" the compiler looks for a file with name starting with "libXi.so" (followed by some version number). The command

```
locate libXi.so | xargs rpm -qf | sort -u
```

gives

```
libXi-1.1.3-4.fc9.i386
libXi-1.1.3-4.fc9.x86_64
libXi-debuginfo-1.1.3-4.fc9.x86_64
libXi-devel-1.1.3-4.fc9.x86_64
```

on my Fedora 10 system, so you are probably missing the *libXi-devel* package.

Comment: (the -devel package creates a symlink from libXi-x.y.z to libXi.so)